# Disconnect hot reloading for a particular tab, through devtools console, for angular apps

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

Is there a way to disconnect the web sockets from hot reloading my angular app, for a particular browser tab by using devtools console window?

I would need to keep the app at a particular state while I have another instance open in another tab that will have enabled hot reloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run your app twice - one through the dev server with websocket reloading (your `ng serve`) and the second one without the dev server.

```
ng build 
&& cd ./dist 
&& npx live-server --entry-file index.html --port <SOMETHING OTHER THAN 4200>
```

or

```
ng serve --live-reload false --port <SOMETHING OTHER THAN 4200>
```

Now you can access your static app at `localhost:<SOMETHING OTHER THAN 4200>`.

Hope this helps a little :-)

Comment: I used ng serve --live-reload false --port 4300 but still reloaded my app

Comment: Doesn't do that form me :-(. Try `ng serve --live-reload false --port 4300 --watch false` - this disables rebuilding as well as reload.

Comment: still refreshing my app

Comment: In that case, try hosting the built app with a live-server. Otherwise, please provide some more details about your setup so I can have a look...

Comment: just a regular ng app created by CLI on localhost

Answer (score 3):

just do `ng serve --live-reload false`

Update Your CLI version first to the latest one.

Comment: I don't know to whom should I validate the answer, both are correct

Comment: Roll a dice ;-)